# String to jQuery object, replace attribute and then back to string again (see JS Fiddle)

Tags: javascript, jquery

http://jsfiddle.net/r4KL9/

This should replace all classes with the corresponding data-change attribute.

So if I had:

```
<div class="hello" data-change="new-class">
```

...I would expect it to return

```
<div class="new-class" data-change="new-class">
```

My code changes one of them (the one on the button) but not the other.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks for any help.

--

Apparently I need to post the JS Fiddle code too:

```
var str = '<div class="original-class" data-change="new-class">Hello</div><div class="class-123"><input type="button" class="start-class" data-change="any-new-class" value="Click Me"></div>';

var html = $('<div/>').html(str).contents();

$('[data-change]', html).attr('class', function() { return $(this).data('change') });

alert( $(html).parent().html() );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var html = $('<div/>').html(str).find('[data-change]').attr('class', function () {
    return $(this).data('change');
}).end().html();

alert(html);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/n8zMN/

Comment: Perfect. If only I could up-vote (and post comments without waiting 15 seconds apart).

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
$('[data-change]', html).attr('class', function() { return $(this).attr('data-change') });
```

EDIT:

```
var html = $(str);
html.filter('[data-change]').attr('class', function() { return $(this).data('change') });
```

I think it works: http://jsfiddle.net/r4KL9/2/

Comment: Thanks, I ended up trying the other answer which worked, but I think yours looks good too.